# Asus USB Display via Displaylink Screen Artifacts and Touchpad Delay

Tags: ubuntu, usb, display, touchpad, displaylink

System Information

```
Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
Product Name: GS63VR 7RF
Version: REV:1.0
```

Display Model

```
MB169B+
```

DisplayLink Version

```
1.4.210
```

When the display is plugged in to a USB port two things happen:

1. The touchpad on the laptop has an induced lag in response
2. When you click the mouse, a small artifact appears on the screen showing old pixels (see screenshot below)

[image]

`/var/log/syslog` after plug in, screen active, unplug (identifiable info removed):

```
Dec 17 16:54:58 tom-GS63VR-7RF DisplayLinkManager[6074]: [libevdi] ioctl: drop_master error=-1
Dec 17 16:54:58 tom-GS63VR-7RF DisplayLinkManager[6074]: message repeated 2 times: [ [libevdi] ioctl: drop_master error=-1]
Dec 17 16:54:58 tom-GS63VR-7RF systemd[1]: Stopped DisplayLink Manager Service.
Dec 17 16:55:07 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1461.403436] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Dec 17 16:55:07 tom-GS63VR-7RF mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2"
Dec 17 16:55:07 tom-GS63VR-7RF mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Dec 17 16:55:07 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1461.424021] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=ff0b
Dec 17 16:55:07 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1461.424022] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 17 16:55:07 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1461.424023] usb 2-2: Product: ASUSTEK MB169B+
Dec 17 16:55:07 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1461.424023] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
Dec 17 16:55:07 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1461.424024] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXX
Dec 17 16:55:07 tom-GS63VR-7RF org.freedesktop.fwupd[1262]: (fwupd:2828): libdfu-WARNING **: interface found, but not interface data
Dec 17 16:55:07 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1461.453340] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp62s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:9a8e:55bc:1eca:a62e DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=495965 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Dec 17 16:55:08 tom-GS63VR-7RF systemd[1]: Starting DisplayLink Manager Service...
Dec 17 16:55:08 tom-GS63VR-7RF sh[6198]: libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'drm_kms_helper'
Dec 17 16:55:08 tom-GS63VR-7RF systemd[1]: Started DisplayLink Manager Service.
Dec 17 16:55:10 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1464.219087] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp62s0 OUT= MAC=XXXXXXXXXXXX SRC=192.168.1.104 DST=192.168.1.192 LEN=348 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=51943 LEN=328 
Dec 17 16:55:10 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1464.219780] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp62s0 OUT= MAC=XXXXXXXXXXXX SRC=192.168.1.100 DST=192.168.1.192 LEN=348 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=51943 LEN=328 
Dec 17 16:55:10 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1464.220099] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp62s0 OUT= MAC=XXXXXXXXXXXX SRC=192.168.1.102 DST=192.168.1.192 LEN=348 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=51943 LEN=328 
Dec 17 16:55:11 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1465.220638] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp62s0 OUT= MAC=XXXXXXXXXXXX SRC=192.168.1.102 DST=192.168.1.192 LEN=348 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=51943 LEN=328 
Dec 17 16:55:11 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1465.220994] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp62s0 OUT= MAC=XXXXXXXXXXXX SRC=192.168.1.104 DST=192.168.1.192 LEN=348 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=51943 LEN=328 
Dec 17 16:55:18 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1472.148228] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_disconnect:593 (dev=-1) An unknown connection to XXXXXXXXXXXX tries to close us
Dec 17 16:55:18 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1472.148228] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_disconnect:594  - ignoring
Dec 17 16:55:18 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1472.152436] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_connect:572 (dev=2) Connected with XXXXXXXXXXXX
Dec 17 16:55:18 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1472.152437] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:75 (dev=2) Painter is connected
Dec 17 16:55:18 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1472.152473] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_crtc_state_notify:481 (dev=2) Notifying crtc state: 3
Dec 17 16:55:18 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1472.153428] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:75 (dev=2) Painter is connected
Dec 17 16:55:18 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1472.153430] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_get_edid_copy:215 (dev=2) 00 ff ff
Dec 17 16:55:18 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1472.182767] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_mode_changed_notify:505 (dev=2) Notifying mode changed: 1920x1080@60; bpp 32; 
Dec 17 16:55:18 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1472.182768] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_mode_changed_notify:506 pixel format 875713112
Dec 17 16:55:18 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1472.182772] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_crtc_state_notify:481 (dev=2) Notifying crtc state: 0
Dec 17 16:55:18 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1472.182773] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_dpms_notify:468 (dev=2) Notifying dpms mode: 0
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1480.071507] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Cannot set link state.
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1480.071520] usb usb2-port2: cannot disable (err = -32)
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1480.071534] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 9
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1480.075859] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_disconnect:611 (dev=2) Disconnected from XXXXXXXXXXXX
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1480.075864] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1480.076209] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_disconnect:593 (dev=-1) An unknown connection to XXXXXXXXXXXX tries to close us
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1480.076212] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_disconnect:594  - ignoring
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1480.077639] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:78 Painter is disconnected
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF systemd[1]: Stopping DisplayLink Manager Service...
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1480.093468] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_crtc_state_notify:481 (dev=-1) Notifying crtc state: 3
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1480.093469] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_send_crtc_state:387 Painter is not connected!
Dec 17 16:55:26 tom-GS63VR-7RF kernel: [ 1480.098596] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp62s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:9a8e:55bc:1eca:a62e DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=495965 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Dec 17 16:55:27 tom-GS63VR-7RF DisplayLinkManager[6207]: [libevdi] ioctl: drop_master error=-1
Dec 17 16:55:27 tom-GS63VR-7RF DisplayLinkManager[6207]: message repeated 2 times: [ [libevdi] ioctl: drop_master error=-1]
Dec 17 16:55:27 tom-GS63VR-7RF systemd[1]: Stopped DisplayLink Manager Service.
```

Comment: Are your graphics drivers updated? Is the cable defective? Can you try another cable?

Comment: Yes fully updated to latest stable version.  Tried other cables.  Thanks.

Comment: Has the problem been solved?

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t clear.  No, it has not been solved.

Comment: Do you still have the Ubuntu Installation CD? Does the artifacts still occur in the [Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)?

Comment: Have you installed the latest [DisplayLink driver for Ubuntu](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu) ? See [How to install DisplayLink software on Ubuntu](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

For the correct operation of the DisplayLink device you need to
install the latest DisplayLink driver for Ubuntu

Links :

- [Ubuntu Latest DisplayLink Software Release](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu)
- [How to install DisplayLink software on Ubuntu](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that should have been an assumption that I tried the latest drivers.  Using DisplayLink 4.2.29 this problem still occurs.

Comment: Then all you can do is log a bug report with the developers. Since you have been absent here for the last few days and not answering our questions for giving us the needed info, you really wasted your bounty.